# QGIS 2.6 Where did "Open from template" go?

Tags: print-composer, template

In QGIS 2.4 there was a menu-point in "Composer" (Composer > Open template) where I could open a saved template, see the map I was printing and move the map in the frame to the exact position that I need. How to do that now? The menu-point is missing in QGIS 2.6

If I make a template and save it, I can reopen it, but not see the map, only the placeholder for it. If I delete the map in the template I can create a new, but this will require a lot of tweaking. I'll have to change the scale of the map, make a new ruler because the old one has no connection with the new map and change the layout (line thickness and color) of the ruler.